# adCreative create Error: 'Invalid parameter' code: 1487390

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

Cannot create adCreative. Get an error:

> Adcreative Create Failed: The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later

and in the same error stack:

> message: 'Invalid parameter'
>   code: 1487390

My code:

```
exports.create = (data, campaign) => {
  return new adsSdk.AdCreative({
      body: data.appearance.vacancyDescription,
      image_url: data.appearance.backgroundImage,
      name: `Creative for campaign ${campaign.id}`,
      link_url: data.appearance.link,
      title: data.appearance.linkDescription,
      object_story_spec: {
          instagram_actor_id: 'xxxxxx',
          page_id: 'xxxxx',
          link_data: {
              link: data.appearance.link
      }
    }
  }, `act_xxxxx`)
    .create()
```

I'm using facebook-js-ads-sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of wrong page_id